# gdb on Cygwin: no output in bash

Tags: bash, gdb, cygwin

I just updated my cygwin 64 bit installation to resume a programming project that I left aside quite some time ago. Everything seems to work fine in cygwin, except gdb.

After starting gdb, nothing happens (except a process gdb.exe is started) however no output is displayed in the bash window. The only command that the gdb.exe process seems to respond to is quit which returns to the bash prompt.

Have I missed to setup something essential? Any idea what I should look at to troubleshoot the issue?

Best wishes
Tord

Comment: Not a programming question. Cygwin installation problem are support on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/problems.html

Comment: Make sure you're actually running the Cygwin gdb.  What does `which gdb` output?

Comment: The gdb that is started is H:\cygwin64\bin\gdb.exe

Comment: Have you found a solution by chance, I am struggling with the same problem? Thanks